# Stack Overflow freaks out when googleapis.com is blocked

Tags: feature-request

I can't find any mention of this, but Stack Overflow is unusable if ajax.googleapis.com is not available.  I know for many people Google's availability is not usually in question, but I noticed it when testing for a large corperate client of ours, who literally do block googleapis.com for their staff.  It's also an issue in countries like Iran where Google is blocked, or on the off-chance that just googleapis.com goes down (not likely, but still possible).

The work around for this is very simple:
[Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-goo)

Is there any reason this is not done on SO?

---

I just found someone did ask this last year, so this is a duplicate:

[Employer blocks jQuery from Google, DOH!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10071/employer-blocks-jquery-from-google-doh)

Comment: Joel Spolsky mentions ajax.googleapis.com [over here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54186/what-websites-support-the-stack-overflow-community/54200#54200) along with the other sites required for the site to function. I can't comment on the subject of your proposed workaround, though.

Comment: Panic? IE9 Tracking Protection might block it out of the box. See [Can't ask a question when IE Tracking Protection is enabled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80044/cant-ask-a-question-when-ie-tracking-protection-is-enabled).

Answer (score 8):

The behavior is the same as with JavaScript disabled -- **you can still ask and answer questions with JavaScript disabled**, which is the core function of the site. It is not "unusable", it is degraded.

And for those clients which block google.. well, they're breaking the internet for all their users, so I'd say they need to fix that bug first.

Bottom line: not our bug, broken policies = broken users.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.  You're right, unusable is a too strong, and degraded is the right word. All the login boxes are gone, which is a bit confusing, to say the least, you can't vote, comment or accept answers, which are all fairly common. Anyhow, I was more interested why you didn't fallback to locally hosted copies, since I use this technique myself - is there a hidden cost to it or is it simply a time/value equation (very understandable)?

Comment: `they need to fix that bug first.` Great point. Now we need to fix our party-government (or pay for VPNs) to continue enjoying SO. Perhaps I should try injecting jquery.js somewhere in a browser extension.

Comment: FYI, China has blocked almost every Google-owned IP address since late May 2014.

Comment: @ZhangChn actually points out a really good issue why is there no answer?

Comment: From a privacy point of view, blocking Google is not a bug, it is self-defence.