# Cannot save Stack Exchange profile when maps.googleapis.com is blocked

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

When requests to maps.googleapis.com are blocked, clicking on the "Save changes just for this community" button does not have any effect.

The console shows the following error when the page loads:

> ReferenceError: google is not defined
>    StackExchange.user.init()

Related: [Stack Overflow freaks out when googleapis.com is blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64465/stack-overflow-freaks-out-when-googleapis-com-is-blocked).

Comment: I'd say that is a dupe not just related. The answer is don't block Google, or if you do don't expect the site to work.

Comment: @Cai `googleapis.com` includes at least two domains, `ajax.googleapis.com` and `maps.googleapis.com`. The first is heavily relied upon for e.g. jQuery, the latter is only used for non-critical functionality. Therefore it seems reasonable to expect the profile page to still be usable even when `maps.googleapis.com` is blocked for some reason.

Comment: Can confirm that if you do block requests for "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places" the save button does indeed stop to work. While one may argue that blocking maps.googleapis isn't much needed (it isn't google analytics.. ) one may still wonder why its absence should block the save operation.

Comment: @Cai: Anybody using a whitelisting-based security solution that's subdomain-specific, such as NoScript, RequestPolicy, and the like?

Comment: @Cai: That is *not* how good security practice works. Unless I have some good reason to actually *use* maps., I'm not going to let it run. What's the point of increasing my attack surface for everything I run across? And "some dumb code on SE that has nothing at all to do with mapping won't run otherwise" is a really frustrating reason to have to increase my attack surface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added some logic to check whether the google objects are available - if not, their lack of existence will no longer block saving the profile page.

With you in the next build.

Comment: [It looks like the check is a bit broken.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295768)