# Blocking google.com and maps.googleapis.com breaks the site

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was told on meta.rpg that this question makes more sense here since it is about general site operation:

I would like to change my profile, but for some reason the profile page breaks because I blocked scripts from maps.googleapis.com. Whatever map feature that is, it cannot be so essential to the site that the page should not need to bother with graceful degradation, can it?

Also I know the Google recaptcha is a really handy thing, but aside from allowing Google to track stackexchange users, recaptcha is also hardly the most secure captcha.

Even the ajax.googleapis.com could be backed by secondary cdns easily.

My point is, it shouldn't be hard to modify the site to allow its use to users who block Google scripts. Maybe I am just 'one of those', but in my experience a suprising amount of people seek to avoid Google tracking. So wouldn't it be worth the (little) effort?

I see a similar question at "[Cannot save Stack Exchange profile when maps.googleapis.com is blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285359/cannot-save-profile-when-maps-googleapis-com-is-blocked)", but at least on rpg.stackexchange the mentioned fix has not occured yet.

**Note**: ajax.googleapis.com is whitelisted. The console tells me `google is not defined`.

Comment: are you sure you're just blocking `maps.googleapis.com` and not all from `googleapis.com`? jQuery is loaded from `ajax.googleapis.com` so if you block all of googleapis you block jquery

Comment: @Memor-X: No, I've verified in the past that the profile page code has a specific and unique dependency on the mapping API, presumably in case someone wants to do something with their location? It's irritatingly fragile.

Comment: @NathanTuggy ahhhh....\*checks it out\* oh hey there it is. i generally use a fake location and never noticed it before

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The profile editing breakage turns out to be caused by a simple bug in [user.js](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/user.en.js).  Specifically, the line that currently reads:

```js
if (StackExchange.options.site.isEnterprise || !(google && google.maps))
```

should actually read:

```js
if (StackExchange.options.site.isEnterprise || !(window.google && google.maps))
```

(See also: [What is the correct way to check if a global variable exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596315/what-is-the-correct-way-to-check-if-a-global-variable-exists) on SO.)

Comment: That should be fixed now.