# Can we have a list of all the Stack Exchange domains somewhere, for firewall purposes?

Tags: support, domain-names

I work behind an really annoying firewall, and I just want the net admin to add all the SE websites to the whitelist. Right now I've lost access to Stack Overflow's authentication, but not Meta's... so I have to come here before I log in there.

It's driving me nuts. Basically I just want to add an exclusion rule for all SE domains; not *only* the website domains, but also the content domains such as gravatar.com, quantserve.com, the domain that holds static content, etc...

Comment: This question screws with my head. Asked March 2nd, 2011. Answered June 18th, 2010.

Comment: @J.Steen the mysterious magic of merging...

Comment: The truth is I'm a time traveler.

Comment: @Peanut the [tag:subdomains] tag should be used for actual sub domains of stackexchange.com, however domains like sstatic.net, gravatar.com etc are not, by any means, such sub domains. This tag does not fit here.

Comment: Related: [How many TLDs are currently owned by Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164054/335251)

Comment: The single source of truth for the site list is *[How can I get URLs and site names for a cross-site SEDE query?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359794/how-can-i-get-urls-and-site-names-for-a-cross-site-sede-query/359796#359796)*.

Answer (score 49):

I'm a Community Wiki answer; please update me!

Stack Exchange sites can be found on these domains (or subdomains, e.g. *.stackexchange.com (including *.meta.stackexchange.com)):

| Domain | Site |
| --- | --- |
| askubuntu.com | [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) |
| mathoverflow.net | [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) |
| serverfault.com | [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) |
| stackoverflow.com | [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) |
| stackexchange.com | [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com) |
| stackapps.com | [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) |
| superuser.com | [Super User](https://superuser.com/) |

stackexchange.com includes first level domains, and second level domains:  *.*.stackexchange.com

The following domains (and in most cases their subdomains) are necessary to view Stack Exchange content and participate on Stack Exchange:

| Domain | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| ajax.googleapis.com | some JavaScript (jQuery, etc.) |
| i.stack.imgur.com | User Images |
| cdnjs.cloudflare.com | MathJax on supported sites |
| *.sstatic.net | static content (JavaScript, CSS, images, etc) |
| stacksnippets.net | code snippets on Stack Overflow |

These ones are required for "normal" site usage on any site.  In other words, if you just want to let your employees browse and post on Stack Overflow, but not waste time at [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour), then you'll need to include Stack Overflow and all these dependencies.

The following additional domains are required to enable additional features:

| Domain | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| stackauth.com | global login (no longer needed due to [Universal Login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153)) |
| gravatar.com | to see user avatars of users using Gravatar |
| graph.facebook.com | to see user avatars of users using their Facebook profile photo |
| *.googleusercontent.com | to see user avatars of users using their Google profile photo |
| *.quantserve.com | Site Analytics |
| *.google-analytics.com | Site Analytics |
| *.scorecardresearch.com | Site Analytics |
| cdn.cookielaw.org | Cookies Consent dialog |

Related domains, not needed for viewing/using the regular Q/A sites:

| Domain | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| blogoverflow.com | viewing archived [Blog Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291741/377214) site blogs |
| stackmod.blog | [community blog](https://stackmod.blog) |
| stackoverflow.blog | [company blog](https://stackoverflow.blog) |
| stackoverflowbusiness.com | [business site](https://stackoverflowbusiness.com) |
| stackoverflowsolutions.com | [marketing purposes and swag email](https://stackoverflowsolutions.com/). [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back) |
| stackoverflowteams.com | [Teams](https://stackoverflow.co/teams) |
| stackoverflow.co | [Data requests](https://policies.stackoverflow.co/data-request/) |
| stackoverflow.help | [Teams help](https://stackoverflow.help/en/) |
| tex-talk.net | [TeX and LaTeX blog](https://tex-talk.net) |
| thesffblog.com | [science fiction and fantasy community blog](https://thesffblog.com) |
| stackoverflow.email | [centralized email services across the entire Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390598/what-email-domains-are-known-to-be-used-by-stack-exchange) |

You can get a complete (and always up to date) list of Stack Exchange site URLs [from the API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites). There are [wrapper libraries](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/library) in many languages for reading the API.

Comment: `wget -qO-  http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites | gunzip | grep -oh \"htt.*\"  | uniq > log.txt`

Comment: comma seperated list of all the main domains listed above: `askubuntu.com, mathoverflow.net, blogoverflow.com, serverfault.com, stackoverflow.com, stackexchange.com, stackapps.com, stackmod.blog, stackoverflow.blog, stackoverflowbusiness.com, superuser.com, tex-talk.net, thesffblog.com`

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning https://stackoverflow.co (which is [the domain that the about-the-company pages moved to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415962/1478931)). There's also https://stackoverflowsolutions.com/, which contains guidance on the company's paid products: Teams, Collectives, Advertising, and Employer Branding. (Some folks may also have received support emails from/linking to support.stackenterprise.co?) That said, I'm not sure where/how/whether that info belongs in this post, since they're not SE site domains specifically, and aren't needed to use our Q&A sites.

Comment: (Oh, and we also send emails related to the Q&A sites from a `stackoverflow.email` domain; see [this MSO post for details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338334/1478931).)

Comment: Looks like blogoverflow.com no longer exists

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a request to stacksnippets.net - at the very least, it never shows up in NoScript's list of domains.

Comment: I've edited this list to include stackoverflow.co, since https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396794/upcoming-privacy-updates-removal-of-the-activity-data-section-and-google-conver?cb=1 linked to https://policies.stackoverflow.co/data-request/ - and hence confirmed it was an official domain. Though I did check to make sure the `.co` was not a typo for `.com`.

Answer (score 33):

***.sstatic.net** has all our static files. This is pretty much required to use the sites.

**ajax.googleapis.com** has JavaScript that helps the site function as expected. Pretty much required.

**stackauth.com** is needed for global login. Optional, but convenient if you're active on several Stack Exchange sites.

***.gravatar.com** has the little icons next to people's names. Optional, but nice.

**imgur.com** hosts pictures that some users upload.

The other dependencies (***.quantserve.com**, ***.google-analytics.com**) are used for our own analytics, letting us know how many visitors we get. Those are optional and the site works fine without them.

Comment: How will this change if a CDN is implemented?

Comment: @nhinkle: It won't -- we're using a subdomain of sstatic.net, so "*.sstatic.net" covers that.

Comment: I know that Joel is badass and all, but how on earth did he answer a question that was asked in 2011, back in 2010 without breaking the laws of physics?

Comment: @OctavianDamiean - it was merged - [What websites support the Stack Overflow community?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54186/what-websites-support-the-stack-overflow-community)