# Unable to load Stack Exchange Chat when on VPN

Tags: bug, chat

I recently started using a VPN service while accessing Internet on all my computers (Specifically [NordVPN](https://nordvpn.com)). While the various network sites appear to work fine, I am unable to load the [Stack Exchange Network Chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com). Initially I shrugged assuming that the site was down.

[image]

However, after observing that this persisted for a long time, out of curiosity, I turned off VPN. And I was able to load the site fine.

I primarily use latest public build of Safari Version 12.1.2, on current public version of macOS Mojave 10.14.6. I was able to reproduce the issue with other popular Web browsers.

My question is, is this by design? If not, what could be possible causing the Chat site to not load while the various other SE sites work fine while on VPN.

Comment: I'm using Private Internet Access with no issues on Windows 10. This is probably an issue with NordVPN's DNS service, not with Stack Exchange. Have you tried choosing a different VPN location?

Comment: @TheWanderer Thanks. Tried it, but to no avail.

Comment: This is relatively old question, so I am not sure whether you still have problems. There was recently a similar question on [math.meta.se], maybe some suggestions in the answers posted there could help: [What should I do to chat successfully?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32301) I will add that one of the answers also mentioned this post: [Can we have a list of all the Stack Exchange domains somewhere, for firewall purposes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81379)