# What is the refresh frequency of the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, api, caching

I'm using the Stack Exchange API and noticed that a comment that I added just now was not being reflected in the API.

Is there a refresh frequency for the API? If so, what is it?

I was not able to find it in the [docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[According to one of the developers back then](https://stackapps.com/a/3544/34061):

> Every response from the API can be cached for up to a minute, so making the same request multiple times in that time-frame typically won't return different results.

From my experience, there is no refresh frequency, so if you add a comment and only read the post details or the list of comments afterwards, you should see it immediately.

Comment: That is my [impression](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81379/can-we-have-a-list-of-all-the-stack-exchange-domains-somewhere-for-firewall-pur#comment1273979_81383) as well.